# OWIN Configuration not firing Not Authorize if no token is provided

Tags: .net, jwt, owin

I configured my OWIN startup class like such :

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=316888
        app.UseActiveDirectoryFederationServicesBearerAuthentication(
            new ActiveDirectoryFederationServicesBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                MetadataEndpoint = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AdfsMetadataEndpoint"],
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    ValidAudience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"],
                    ValidIssuer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Issuer"]
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Global.asax.cs :

```
public class WebApiApplication : HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
}
```

And my controller :

```
[RoutePrefix("v1/onboarding")]
public class OnboardingController : ApiController
{
    [Route("client")]
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage CreateClient([FromUri] string CIFID)
    {
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Created);
    }
}
```

But when I use postman to call the GET /client without a Bearer token, the call proceeds and I get my 201 response status.

It should trigger a 403 Not Authorized status code if I don't provide the bearer token, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added [Authorize] attribute to the controller.